# Laravel Testing Increasing Memory Use

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

```
Time: 1.89 minutes, Memory: 526.00MB

OK (487 tests, 2324 assertions)
```

This is my phpunittest result from testing my Laravel API, the memory consumption just keeps increasing and feel like i tried all posts and answers across the internet for what keeps racking up memory when testing. From own debugging the App is trashed every test which it should.

Everything is pretty standard, with the createApplication method that looks like this.

```
public function createApplication()
{
    // Ran out of memory
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

    $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

Came to the conclusion that the memory leak is in, which does not get cleaned up properly.

```
$app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
```

Comment: Are you using the DB at all?

Comment: Yes i am using the database.

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andboson/dba379dd879f387ee1fa try profiling it to see where the memory leak could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. I tested it in Laravel 5.5. Set this as the content of the `tests/CreatesApplication.php` file:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected static $application;

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        if (!isset(static::$application)) {
            static::$application = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
            static::$application->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
        }

        return static::$application;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        // Required if you use HTTP tests
        $this->app['auth']->guard(null)->logout();
        $this->app['auth']->shouldUse(null);
        $this->flushSession();

        // Always required
        $this->app = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

This code makes tests use the same Laravel application instance for all tests instead of creating a new instance for each test. Also this causes a faster testing run.

This solution has disadvantages:

- If a test modifies the application, the other tests can fail because they expect an unaltered application.
- If a test uses the `DatabaseTransactions` or the `DatabaseMigrations` trait, the database is reset when all the test of a PHPUnit test run has finished.

Comment: This isn't working in laravel 9. Probably we have to use original `createApplication()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest and the most reliable solution I've found. It doesn't have the disadvantages described in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276971/1118709).

Change the `<phpunit>` tag `processIsolation` attribute value to `true` in the `phpunit.xml` file. An example of the start of a proper `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
...
```

How it works: it makes PhpUnit start a new PHP process for each test. Running tests in separate processes forces PHP to free all the memory after a test is over. It slows down the tests but it's the price for the low memory consumption and the reliability.

Or you can add a [`@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` annotation](http://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/annotations.html#runtestsinseparateprocesses) to the doc block of a test class if you need to run in separate processes only certain tests:

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
class HeavyTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for this for a long time temporarily solving the issue by turning on process isolation. That kind of worked but was super-slow and caused other issues.

The high memory usage is because the Laravel application object contains many references to other objects. PHP isn't very good at garbage collecting objects with many interconnected references so the objects hang around causing massive memory usage.

I solved this by extending builtin Application object and adding my own clean up method that's called after every test:

*Note: This is for Laravel 4.2 but the same principal should work just as well with Laravel 5+.*

Add `app\foundation\Application.php` (this may differ depending on how you're using namespaces).

```
<?php

namespace App\Foundation;

class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    /**
     * Used during unit tests to clear out all the data structures
     * that may contain references.
     * Without this phpunit runs out of memory.
     */
    public function clean()
    {
        unset($this->bootingCallbacks);
        unset($this->bootedCallbacks);
        unset($this->finishCallbacks);
        unset($this->shutdownCallbacks);
        unset($this->middlewares);
        unset($this->serviceProviders);
        unset($this->loadedProviders);
        unset($this->deferredServices);
        unset($this->bindings);
        unset($this->instances);
        unset($this->reboundCallbacks);

        unset($this->resolved);
        unset($this->aliases);
    }

}
```

Ensure Laravel is autoloading the new class by editing the `composer.json` file and adding `app/foundation` to `autoload` > `classmap`. You may want to add the path to `app/start/global.php` (ClassLoader::addDirectories) too.

Edit `bootstrap\start.php` and change `$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;` to `$app = new App\Foundation\Application;`.

Now edit your `app/tests/TestCase.php` and add your own `tearDown` method:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $this->app->clean();
    unset($this->app);
    unset($this->client);
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

All this does is call the `clean()` method after every test essentially removing the references before the object is garbage collected.

Comment: After an upgrade to 5.3 i had to discard my original answer solution, and took yours advice which worked but had to remove the parent teardown else everything works fine

Comment: If you name the method `flush()` instead of `clean()` you can call `parent::tearDown();` without the need for the other 3 lines. The parent tearDown calls a `flush()` method, so in this way you effectively override it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but it was due to Telescope being enabled during unit testing. Adding the following to phpunit.xml decreased my memory usage by around 75%.

```
<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```